# Point to specific class instance from $("*").on?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

Whenever I run this script, every div that includes ".show-more-text" gets handeled.
Allthough, it only interferes with one selected div, but runs multiple times.

I can't find the syntax to solve this and don't know what to search for.

```
<input class="show-more-text ellipsis-desc" value="More">


$(".show-more-text").on("click", function () {
    console.log($(this).val());

    if ($(this).val() == "More") {
        $(this).prev().removeClass("ellipsis-desc").addClass("ellipsis-off");

        $(this).val("Less");
    } else {
        $(this).prev().removeClass("ellipsis-off").addClass("ellipsis-desc");

        $(this).val("More");
    }

});
```

Any ideas would help.

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: What is running multiple times?

Comment: you can shorten this whole function to `$(this).prev().toggleClass('ellipsisdesc ellipsisoff');
$(this).val( $(this).val()=='more'?"Less":'more');`

Comment: @Martijn, what about "Less" and "More"?

Comment: Missed that, editted my comment. That makes two lines total :)

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Martijn!

@MauricePerry: ".show-more-text" exists on multiple places so the function runs according to that. If i click on input, it works but only if the class is repeatedly used to an uneven number... :)